# Check for previous version of application

Tags: c#

I want to show a What's New form in my application. However I need to detect whether it's  a new install, or an upgrade.

I'm using the following code to upgrade the settings:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade)
{
    WhatsNew WhatsNew = new WhatsNew();
    WhatsNew.Show();
    WhatsNew.BringToFront();

    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();                
}
```

The `Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade` is set to `True` by default. However this code will bring up the Whats New form always, even with a new installation.

The `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` doesn't have an event or something which is fired when the upgrade actually was needed, so I have no idea if there was a previous version (and thus show the Whats New form). How do I know if there was a previous version?

Comment: Probably we can't get that info without using system OS registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this using `GetPreviousVersion(string property);`. The downside is that there was a setting needed in a previous version (however in my case it's not an issue - even the first version had atleast **one** setting).

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade)
{
    Object PrevVersion = Properties.Settings.Default.GetPreviousVersion("tooltipDisplay");
    if (PrevVersion != null)
    {
        WhatsNew WhatsNew = new WhatsNew();
        WhatsNew.Show();
        WhatsNew.BringToFront();

        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

This code will check if there's a previous configuration found, and if it is the object `PrevVersion`will not be set to `null`.

Comment: As of VS2015, `GetPreviousVersion()` throws exception if the specified setting is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a setting called something like **currentVersion** which starts off as empty and comparing this with the current assembly version of your application. Something like this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();

            string strVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            string installedVersion = Properties.Settings.Default.installedVersion;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(installedVersion) && installedVersion != strVersion)
            {
                WhatsNew WhatsNew = new WhatsNew();
                WhatsNew.Show();
                WhatsNew.BringToFront();
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.installedVersion = strVersion;
            Properties.Settings.Default.settingsUpgrade = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

This should work providing you update the assembly version for each new version of the application.
The version comparison in my example is obviously very simple, and would also cause the What's New to be displayed if they downgraded as well as if they upgraded, but it should be straightforward to fix that.

Edit: I've updated the code to fix some issues. Basically, calling Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() to get the user settings before trying to get the old version number.

Comment: With this code I still don't know if it's a fresh install or if it's an upgrade. Since `Properties.Settings.Default.currentVersion` is always empty each new version.

Comment: What is the scope of the setting set to? If it is set to Application I believe that changing it to User (so it is stored per-user and not per-application) should resolve this.

Comment: It's at user. However the `Properties.Settings.Default.currentVersion` is always empty (even if you used a previous version), hence you will need to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` to grab the contents of the old configuration files and save them as your current.

Comment: I've updated my code again. I've tested it and it appears to work. It calls Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() if settingsUpgrade is set to True. After doing this it then retrieves the version number (which now comes from from the user settings) and compare this with the assembly version number.

Comment: Yes, I see this code working. Didn't thought about that before. However I just found a more "cleaner" method, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10418642/659731. +1 either way, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global accessible resource, such as system registry.
Placing the current "installed" (if is stand-alone, not actually installed) version number in some place, where any other program can read it.